# Final year Project using Block-Chain technology

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, mist

What Type of Application i can develop using Smart Contracts? (I Need Suggestions for my final year project)

Comment: Short version is: systems where you want decentralization. But "apps using blockchain technology" is a pretty broad term, and even algo trading can be said to be a blockchain app, even it has nothing to do with decentralization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you have basically endless possibilities where you can use block-chain applications. Check this website: https://blockgeeks.com/guides/blockchain-applications/ Maybe you can get some ideas there? Another way is to have a look at the Solidity documentation https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/index.html. There you can find many examples of block-chain applications. I hope that gives you some ideas.